# Why is my VSE Importing a wrong image sequence?

Tags: animation, image, video-sequence-editor

I created a very simple one-minute digital countdown animation (using the add-on "Animation nodes" and using "text" as object) and it seems to be working just fine when i play the animation from the Viewpoint.

I exported the animation in a PNG image sequence and when I import that sequence in the VSE and play the video, it seems like the frames are sort of being anticipated:

It seems like there is always a frame misplaced in the middle of the preceding sequence, so, instead of seeing a smooth change from -let's say- 58 seconds to 57, i see 58 seconds, than 57 seconds (appearing for just one frame), than 58 again, than 57, than 56 (again for just one frame), then 57 and so on.

Overall, the countdown works but because some of the frames are being misplaced, it looks like it's glitching and of course i would like to solve that.

I've checked the PNG images directly in their folder and they are in a correct order, so it seems like VSE is importing them in a wrong one.

I'm new to blender and I would really appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: are you sure it is imported in the name order (and not date order for example)? Also sometimes there are some refresh bugs, just close and reopen Blender and your file

Comment: Thank You so much! yes, i apparently imported the sequence in the date order instead of the name order, I haven't thought of that!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you import your sequence in name order and not in date order. Also sometimes there are some refresh bugs, just close and reopen Blender and your file.